# How to get view position in window while this view is in a layout which is in another layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, widget

I have tried this one (set to Buttons):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        lastTouchXonWindow = event.getX() + v.getX();
        lastTouchYonWindow = event.getY() + v.getY(); 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which works while the view is in the only one layout to the activity but if it's in a layout which in another layout that doesn't works because v.getX() give me the X location in the parent layout and not in the window.

Here is an example of the activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


<!-- Some Widgets ...-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ChallengeLinearChoix12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ChallengeButtonChoix1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="01"
            style="@style/TresGrand"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ChallengeButtonChoix2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="02"
            style="@style/TresGrand"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FurtherMore I have tried this which generate error "Cannot resolve the method getY()":

```
        lastTouchY =  event.getY() + v.getY() + v.getParent().getY();
```

Comment: use event.getRawX(), event.getRawY(). Touch coordinates can be obtained based on the entire window.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with .getRawX() for the absolute touch's location (thanks to pistolcaffe) then .getLocationOnScreen() for the absolute view's location

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    layoutParent.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        lastTouchX =  event.getRawX() - location[0];
        lastTouchY =  event.getRawY() - location[1];

        textAnimationScore.setText(""+location[1]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I had to add the parent layout in the Java Activity, I'm surprised that v.getRootView().getLocationOnScreen(location) give 0 instead 160.